# Is myopenrouter.com reputable?

Tags: router, dd-wrt

I really want to flash dd-wrt on my netgear r6300 v1, however the main dd-wrt website's database is extremely outdated.

I keep being re-directed by search results to this [page](http://www.myopenrouter.com/download/list?cat=92), but I'm a little hesitant to flash a firmware shared by a website of aggregators. Though they may be trustworthy.

I know Kong is one of the main ddwrt submitters after BrainSlayer, but what is the repute of myopenrouter.com; namely, does this community agree that is it trustworthy?

I'm really not willing to spend time pulling and compiling DD-WRT myself.

Comment: You can get Kong's releases for the r6300v1 from [Kong's download page](http://desipro.de/ddwrt/K3-AC/).

Answer (score 2):

I can guarantee you that MyOpenRouter is not website based on aggregators. All downloads are added manually.
Netgear.com also recommends the site for it's 'open source' routers as you can see under Features. http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-routers/WNR3500L.aspx

One thing to keep in mind though is that new updates from developers like Kong may not show up there as fast as you will find them on their own sites.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding David Schwartz's comment on 7/9/14 above, it seems that that website has had some changes. That location seems to be where the current testing dev builds are kept.

Quoting the readme on the FTP server one of the dd-wrt Dev's, Kong, now hosts his own files directly not on the myopenrouter.com servers

> Regular dd-wrt builds can be found here:
>
> ftp://ftp.dd-wrt.com/betas/2015/
>
> This location now contains my personal test builds.